# Java equivalent to python EnvironmentError?

Tags: java, exception

Is there any equivalent to `EnvironmentError` from python in java? Example follows:

```
raise EnvironmentError
```

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException()`? `IllegalStateException`? Create your own?

Comment: Runtime not precisely as its not an unchecked exception, though`IllegalStateException` fits close enough, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java we take a rather myopic point of view and assume that we are in control of virtually every error that can come up (in the case of anything that is an `Exception`), or we assume that this is the result of some extraneous behavior (`RuntimeException`).  However, both of those exceptions are still within some realm of our control.

The one thing that happens that's *outside* of our control are `Error`s.  Y'know, things like running out of memory would be well outside of our control.  Since `EnvironmentError` deals with errors outside the purview of Python, I would believe that `Error` is its Java counterpart *in spirit*.

In *practice*, it's likely closer to an `Exception`, given that it deals with `OSError` and `IOError` (and those are things that Java believes it can recover from, for the most part).